# What's the music playing at the beginning of episode 130?

Tags: music, bleach

What's the name of the soundtrack at the beginning of episode 130 at around minute 3:02? It is repeated through the anime, but I don't remember which episode I first heard it in.

Answer (score 1):

The music you are looking for is [Pain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFtfIQkGvUM). It is part of the musics of Bleach that have not been released in any OST.